# Jquery function erase the parameters action using Ajax.Beginform

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, action, partial-views

I have a strange behavior.

I'm using `Ajax.beginForm` to pass display a partial view

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ManageSeason", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "TableTournaments",
    HttpMethod = "POST",

    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
    {
        //My Parameters to pass on the action
    }

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_TableTournaments"); }
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
```

I have an Action which get the result in an object `CreateSeasonParamObject`

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ManageSeason(CreateSeasonParamObject csp)
        {
            //Do stuff

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView(msvm);
            }
            return View(msvm);
        }
```

it's working well!

But when i want to use a Jquery function to disable my parameters after the form submit. My  `ManageSeason` get always a null object

This is my Jquery function

```
  $('#buttonCreateSeasonParam').click(function (e) {
       //Disable my parameters
    });
```

What is the problem? I try to use the Jquery Ajax, but it's not a success for me!

Comment: What do you mean _disable my parameters_? Do you mean disable the form controls? - Disabled controls do not post back a value so the properties of `csp` will be their default (and `csp` will not be `null` despite what you claim). And as a side note, `ValidationSummary` is not inside you `<form>` tags so its a bit pointless

Comment: Yes the validation summary it's an old form. I remove it. i have an other inside the form.

Comment: _I have an other inside the form_? That's nested forms which is invalid html and not supported

Comment: I mean : The action displays a table value based on my form control. So I do not want the user to change the form control values ​​again after the dependent table is displayed.

Comment: Then make them readonly, not disabled (disabled controls do not submit a value)

Comment: Great the readonly, i understand why now! but finally i used someting like  `if($('#tableTournamentsCreateSeason').is(':visible'))`. because my page seems to be reloaded, and the readonly property disappear.